# Connection issues with turbo streams and custom action cable channel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actioncable, hotwire-rails

I'm trying to setup a turbo stream connection with a custom action cable channel from an erb view like this:

View

```
<%= turbo_stream_from "image_viewer_#{@image.id}", channel: "ImageViewerChannel", data: {image_id: @image.id} %>
<%= turbo_frame_tag "connected_users" do %>
  <%= render 'connected_users', count: 0 %>
<% end %>
```

Channel

```rb
class ImageViewerChannel <  ApplicationCable::Channel
  extend Turbo::Streams::Broadcasts, Turbo::Streams::StreamName
  include Turbo::Streams::StreamName::ClassMethods

  @@connected_users_count = 0

  def subscribed
    @@connected_users_count += 1
    @image_id = params[:image_id]
    stream_from "image_viewer_#{@image_id}"
    broadcast_connected_users_count
  end

.....


  private

  def broadcast_connected_users_count
    ActionCable.server.broadcast(
      "image_viewer_#{@image_id}",
      Turbo::StreamsChannel.broadcast_replace_to(
        "connected_users",
        target: "connected_users",
        partial: "images/connected_users",
        locals: { count: @@connected_users_count }
      )
    )
  end
```

But I can't seem to get the connection working properly, I've confirmed `redis` is running and the channel is accepting connections by using a stimulus controller which successfully establishes a connection using the elevant stream identifier so my assumption is that its a problem in the view. I've also confirmed the `@image` instance variable is being set properly from the relevant controller and it produces the following output in HTML

```html
<turbo-cable-stream-source channel="ImageViewerChannel" data-image-id="14" signed-stream-name="ImltYWdlX3ZpZXdlcl8xNCI=--0eeda72e7a5478708717f1013f6a650e5b36c5f313a38a50a980e004a841b092"></turbo-cable-stream-source>
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

EDIT:

Adding more details to assist with further debugging, I've stripped everything else from `show.html.erb` so it just looks like this:

```
<%= turbo_stream_from "image_viewer_#{@image.id}", channel: "ImageViewerChannel", data: {image_id: @image.id} %>
<%= tag.div id: :connected_users do %>
  <%= render "images/connected_users", count: 0 %>
<% end %>
```

Controller:

```rb
  def show
    @image = Image.find(params[:id])
  end
```

And the full html output:

```html
<main class="container mx-auto mt-28 px-5 flex">
  <turbo-cable-stream-source channel="ImageViewerChannel" data-image-id="15" signed-stream-name="ImltYWdlX3ZpZXdlcl8xNSI=--b6210244563c1b1182cf3b15f63f8425aae5eb267eb38660507bae79fb80e1ca"></turbo-cable-stream-source>
  <div id="connected_users">
    <p> Medcial Image Viewer - Connected Users: 0 </p>
  </div>
</main>
```

App logs:

```
Started GET "/images/15" for 127.0.0.1 at 2024-03-01 16:31:51 +0500
Processing by ImagesController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"15"}
  Image Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "images".* FROM "images" WHERE "images"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 15], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/images_controller.rb:28:in `set_image'
  CACHE Image Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "images".* FROM "images" WHERE "images"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 15], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/images_controller.rb:22:in `show'
  Rendering layout layouts/application.html.erb
  Rendering images/show.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered images/_connected_users.erb (Duration: 0.0ms | Allocations: 14)
  Rendered images/show.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 0.3ms | Allocations: 244)
  Rendered layout layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 6.3ms | Allocations: 6107)
Completed 200 OK in 8ms (Views: 6.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.1ms | Allocations: 7407)
```

Redis is running:

```bash
brew services                                                                                           main * ] 4:30 pm
Name          Status     User        File
postgresql@14 error  256 xyz ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql@14.plist
redis         started   xyz  ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.redis.plist
```

Comment: do you have any errors in browser console. there is no connection to `/cable` that's why there are no updates. connection should be established automatically by turbo (`import "@hotwired/turbo-rails`)

Answer (score 0):

A few things that jump out: you've set up your own turbo stream channel but still sending updates through `Turbo::StreamsChannel`. You're not subscribed to `connected_users` to receive any updates. `broadcast_replace_to` will **replace** your turbo frame, which means you won't have a target after the first update. You don't need a turbo frame for turbo streams to work.

```rb
class ImageViewerChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  include Turbo::Streams::Broadcasts
  include Turbo::Streams::StreamName

  @@connected_users_count = 0

  def subscribed
    @@connected_users_count += 1
    @image_id = params[:image_id]
    stream_from "image_viewer_#{@image_id}"
    broadcast_connected_users_count
  end

  private

    def broadcast_connected_users_count
      # NOTE: if you `extend Turbo::Streams::Broadcasts` then you have to 
      #       call it as a class method `ImageViewerChannel.broadcast_update_to`
      broadcast_update_to(
        "image_viewer_#{@image_id}",     # <= this is where you're streaming from
                                         #    that's where the broadcast goes
        target: "connected_users",
        partial: "images/connected_users",
        locals: {count: @@connected_users_count}
      )
    end
end
```

```rb
<%= turbo_stream_from "image_viewer_#{@image.id}", channel: "ImageViewerChannel", data: {image_id: @image.id} %>

<%= tag.div id: :connected_users do %>
  <%= render "images/connected_users", count: 0 %>
<% end %>
```

---

I think you could also just inherit from `Turbo::StreamsChannel`:

```rb
class ImageViewerChannel < Turbo::StreamsChannel
  @@connected_users_count = 0

  def subscribed
    super
    @@connected_users_count += 1
    broadcast_connected_users_count
  end

  private

    def broadcast_connected_users_count
      ImageViewerChannel.broadcast_update_to(
        verified_stream_name_from_params,
        target: "connected_users",
        partial: "images/connected_users",
        locals: {count: @@connected_users_count}
      )
    end
end
```

---

**Update**

This is what I get:

```html
<turbo-cable-stream-source channel="ImageViewerChannel" data-image-id="1" signed-stream-name="ImltYWdlX3ZpZXdlcl8xIg==--e5b0cbf8cc93373099c4c70b75fe8e397096882718b43d3638649d1da1c225ee" connected=""></turbo-cable-stream-source>

<div id="connected_users">
  <div> 2 </div>
</div>
```

```bash
  Rendered images/_connected_users.html.erb (Duration: 0.1ms | Allocations: 10)
ImageViewerChannel is streaming from image_viewer_1
[ActionCable] Broadcasting to image_viewer_1: "<turbo-stream action=\"update\" target=\"connected_users\"><template><div> 2 </div>\n</template></turbo-stream>"
ImageViewerChannel is transmitting the subscription confirmation
ImageViewerChannel transmitting "<turbo-stream action=\"update\" target=\"connected_users\"><template><div> 2 </div>\n</template></turbo-stream>" (via streamed from image_viewer_1)
ImageViewerChannel transmitting "<turbo-stream action=\"update\" target=\"connected_users\"><template><div> 2 </div>\n</template></turbo-stream>" (via streamed from image_viewer_1)
```

and cable message:

```json
{
  "identifier": "{\"channel\":\"ImageViewerChannel\",\"signed_stream_name\":\"ImltYWdlX3ZpZXdlcl8xIg==--e5b0cbf8cc93373099c4c70b75fe8e397096882718b43d3638649d1da1c225ee\",\"image_id\":\"1\"}",
  "message": "<turbo-stream action=\"update\" target=\"connected_users\"><template><div> 2 </div>\n</template></turbo-stream>"
}
```

Comment: Hey @Alex

I tried your solution mate and it doesn't seem to work either. I think the problem is connecting with the custom channel via the `turbo_stream_from` helper.

Comment: Here's the full `show.html.erb` file:

Comment: @evilGenious edit your question if you have something new to show me. see update, if you want to compare with your logs.

Comment: Thanks @Alex

I've updated my question to include some more information.